# How-to create SQL-script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I use MSSQL Management Studio 2005 Express Edition, and I have more than 100 stored procedures. How create sql-script which contain **only** stored procedures? Thanks.

Comment: right click on your database name and then select task -> Generate Script -> and check stored procedures in it and the finish i hope this will do the work for you.

Answer (score 5):

Right click on the database -> Tasks -> Generate Scripts -> Go through the steps -> There are check boxes to select Tables, SPs, UDFs and Users. Select only SPs and create the script.

Here is the starting point.

[image]

Comment: just a minor correction: Right click on the database -> Tasks -> Generate Scripts -> ...

Answer (score 2):

If you do `exec SP_HelpText StoredProcedureNameGoesHere`, you will get the full script of that procedure.

Do this to get 5 procedures (you get the picture)

```
exec SP_HelpText StoredProcedure01
exec SP_HelpText StoredProcedure02
exec SP_HelpText StoredProcedure03
exec SP_HelpText StoredProcedure04
exec SP_HelpText StoredProcedure05
```

Here's a script to generate the script for all procedures in your db.

```
SELECT 'Exec sp_Helptext ' + SPECIFIC_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Routines
```

Answer (score 1):

Open Databases >> DBName >> Programability >> Stored Procedures in Object Explorer Details and then select all procedures except "System Stored Procedures" folder and right click on it and select "Script Stored Procedures as >> Create To >>" option.

[image]

Comment: The OP did not ask how to script out a stored procedure. But how to script only the stored procedures in his database.

Comment: @hughjadick : jadick This will shows only SPs, not another tables or functions.

Comment: If you read the original question the author is asking for ALL stored procedures. Not ONE stored procedure.

Comment: @hughjadick : If you check my answer I written to select all stored procedures and then right click. In screenshot I have one SP so.

Comment: it is impossible to select more than one stored procedures in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: @hughjadick : Can you see my updated answer ? Now I have doubt on you. have you worked with SQL server ?

Comment: the OP said they are using SQL Server 2005 Management Studio Express Edition. You are using 2008R2 or 2011. The OP does not have access to the same tooling you have. If you are unable to accept you did not read the original question properly then that is your concern not mine.

Comment: @hughjadick : It is also possible in SQL 2005 Express Edition.

Comment: If you are correct about that then I apologise for my original comment. However, I am not going to install SQL 2005 Express Edition to check.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on ur database name -> Select Task -> Generate Script -> Next -> Next -> Select things to be scripted ->next - > Select All -> Finish

i have posted an image for help.

[image: Generating script from existing stored procedures]